# Is it possible to cast multiple columns of a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a multi-column pyspark dataframe, and I need to convert the string types to the correct types, for example:

I'm doing like this currently

```
df = df.withColumn(col_name, col(col_name).cast('float') \
.withColumn(col_id, col(col_id).cast('int') \
.withColumn(col_city, col(col_city).cast('string') \
.withColumn(col_date, col(col_date).cast('date') \
.withColumn(col_code, col(col_code).cast('bigint')
```

is it possible to create a list with the types and pass it at once to all columns?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to have some mapping as dictionary, or something like, and then generate correct `select` statement (you can use `withColumn`, but usually it can lead to performance problems).  Something like this:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
mapping = {'col1':'float', ....}
df = .... # your input data
rest_cols = [F.col(cl) for cl in df.columns if cl not in mapping]
conv_cols = [F.col(cl_name).cast(cl_type).alias(cl_name) 
   for cl_name, cl_type in mapping.items()
   if cl_name in df.columns]
conv_df.select(*rest_cols, *conv_cols)
```

Comment: Wow...beautiful!

Comment: There is an issue in the code, with `closing parenthesis ')' does not match opening parenthesis` in the following line:
`for cl_name, cl_type in mapping.items())`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the ordering of columns in the dataframe as I did, here's an adaptation of @Alex Ott's answer:

```
mapping = {'col1': 'float', ....}
df = .... # your input data
for c in df.columns:
   if c in mapping.keys():
      df = df.withColumn(c, df[c].cast(mapping[c]))
```

This basically just iterates over each of the column names in the dataframe, performing any cast for only those that are in the `mapping` dict.